# Using while loop with counter in django template

Tags: python, django, loops, while-loop

I need to put a counter in while loop in template. So I did:

```
<tbody> 
    {% with count=1 %}
    {% while count <={{orders_count}}: %}
        {% for order in orders %}
            <tr>
                <td style="width:5%;"></td>
                <td>{{count}}</td>
                <td>{{order.name}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% count+=1 %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwhile %}
    {% endwith %}
</tbody>
```

But finaly I have the following error:

```
Invalid block tag on line 216: 'while', expected 'endwith'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a `while` loop here, you can simply make use of the [**`|slice`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
<tbody> 
    {% for order in orders|slice:orders_count %}
        <tr>
            <td style="width:5%;"></td>
            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

But slicing, etc. does *not* really belong in the *template*. You normally do that in the *view*.

Comment: Thanks but I think `forloop.counter` is true.

Comment: Does pattern `|slice:orders_count` make more resources(RAM/CPU) in comparison with the state which we don't type it?

Comment: @M.J: not significantly no. But what is `order_count`? If it is just the number of items in `orders`, then you should not pass it to the template *anyway*.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
<tbody> 
    {% for order in orders %}
        <tr>
            <td style="width:5%;"></td>
            <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
            <td>{{order.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```